# Angular.js how to save resource from watch?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, factory, watch

I get an array with resouces and try to auto save it on change.

```
$scope.items = Item.query();

$scope.$watch('items', function(newval, oldval, scope){
    scope.$save();
}, true);
```

Code above returns me

> TypeError: undefined is not a function

Which is correct way to save resource, that was changed? Thank you.

**UPDATE:**

I was try to use ng-change, as described here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/guzTpRuwkt0, it even sends the request, but loosing id of item.

> PUT /api/v1/items - 404

May be something wrong at factory?

```
.factory('Item', function($resource){
    return $resource('http://localhost:3000/api/v1/items/:id', {id:'@id'}, {
        update: {
            method: 'PUT'
        }
    });
});
```

**SECOND UPDATE**

My bad, I just forgot to set id in parameters:

```
 ng-change="item.$update({id: item._id})"
```